# Save error in simple form

Tags: php, yii2, save, jquery-select2

I have simple form using Select2 widget. The part I have problem with looks like that:

```
<?php
$form->field($model, 'payment_option_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => [],
    'id' => 'payment-option-id-select-field',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select payment')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 0,
        'language' => [
            'errorLoading' => new JsExpression("function () { return 'Waiting for results...'; }"),
        ],
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => '#',
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { console.log(params); return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
    ]])->label(Yii::t('app', Yii::t('app', 'Payment')))
?>
```

The JS is working correctly, in the end I get my select field filled with option that I want it to have, so everything seems fine. I choose one option, and when I submit the form, I get a save error: payment_option_id contains invalid value. When I var_dump what my $_POST has, it looks alright, it contains the right value afterall, but it doesn't want to save that record.

var_dump($_POST) :

```
array (size=2)
'Payments' => 
      array (size=5)
              'amount' => string '3567' (length=4)
              'date' => string '2017-02-23' (length=10)
              'deal_id' => string '5' (length=1)
              'buyer_id' => string '5' (length=1)
              'payment_option_id' => string '18' (length=2)
'submit' => string 'create' (length=6)
```

Rules that I have in PaymentOption model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['amount', 'date', 'deal_id', 'user_id'], 'required'],
            [['amount'], 'number'],
            [['date', 'buyer_id'], 'safe'],
            [['deal_id', 'user_id', 'payment_option_id'], 'integer'],
            [['deal_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Deals::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['deal_id' => 'id']],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
            [['payment_option_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['payment_option_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: can you show the result of var_dump?

Comment: @Chinmay added.

Comment: Seems to be ok .. can you also show your save logic?

Comment: please update  your question an show the related  rules  in model

Comment: @scaisEdge already done :)

Comment: @Chinmay already done :)

Comment: the only  fact is that you have the value as string but you have integer in rules .. how  the column payment_option_id  is declared in your table?

Comment: @scaisEdge In my table it's integer. But deal_id also is declared as integer (both in rules and the table), but in $_POST is received as string, yet everything works okay.

Comment: I think the rule for "payment_option_id" uses the wrong model. My assumption is that it should not map to the User model, but to another model. The error is a validation error that no User model with id=18 exists.

Comment: @JannesBotis that was it, I'm a victim of copy-pasting too much when too tired :)